# Access camera for multiple buttons

Tags: java, android

How do I set up multiple buttons to access the camera and save the photo?

I have figured out how to have one button do this task, but cannot figure out how to get multiple buttons to do this.

My Java Code so far:

```
package com.example.android.phototaker;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView result;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signbutton);
        result = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }

    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            result.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you looking to have all three buttons do the same thing or do different things?

Comment: I have three buttons, I want each to access the camera and take a unique picture.  I have been able to get one button to access the camera and take a picture (script above), but cannot get a second button to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

By multiple buttons do you mean, different buttons opening up the camera?
If so, you will need to add an onclick listener for those buttons.

Comment: What you can do is copy the same code you used for the first button except chage the button id .

Comment: I tried that and got an error due to there being duplicate intents.  Also I am assuming there is a way to make it less complex, so each button accesses the same intent, as opposed to having the same intent multiple times (i would like to have numerous buttons eventually).  Thanks

Comment: Is there a really good onclicklistener tutorial or writeup I can look at.  I have found some and understand the basics? but still cant get it to work, thanks.

Comment: You can post what you have tried and we can try and solve it together.

Comment: I posted what I have under the question : "onactivityresult for separate thumbnails"